# BigQuery Google Data Transfer Impressions & Cost Don't Match Google Ads UI

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-ads-api

Disclaimer...I'm a Noob

I am writing a query from CampaignStats table that aggregates based on a stripped campaign label. The query returns correct values for all metrics except *Impressions* and *Cost*. No matter what I've tried so far, this figure still doesn't match. Here are the totals for two of my campaigns from yesterday (June 17th):

CampaignStats:

```
Date    label   Impressions cost    clicks  avg_cpc
6/17/2022   sat_brand   2687    140.472666  15  9.3648444
```

[image: CampaignStats Screenshot]

CampaignBasicStats:

```
Date    label   Impressions cost    clicks  avg_cpc
6/17/2022   sat_brand   699 152.620961  15  10.17473073
```

[image: CampaignBasicStats Screenshot]

Utilizing the CampaignBasicStats table, I receive aggregated totals for all metrics that match the UI, including *Impressions* and *Cost*. The issue is there are metrics in CampaignStats and getting some illumination/information on what I may not be doing correct, will help in the future.

I did a JOIN with the *Campaign* table originally; the below query refers to a permanent table that I pulled out separately in case this was a cause of the discrepancy.

Code Below:

```
  SELECT  
  cs.Date,
  
  EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM cs.DATE) AS isoweek,
  
  cl.label,
  
  (SUM(cs.Cost) / 1000000) AS cost,
 
  SUM(cs.Clicks) AS clicks,
  
  CASE WHEN SUM(Clicks)=0 OR SUM(Cost)=0 THEN 0 ELSE
    ((SUM(Cost)/SUM(Clicks))/1000000) END AS avg_cpc,
  
  SUM(cs.Impressions) AS Impressions,
  
  CASE WHEN SUM(cs.Clicks)=0 THEN 0 ELSE
    (SUM(cs.Clicks)/SUM(cs.Impressions)) END AS ctr,
  
  SUM(cs.Conversions) as conversions,
  
  CASE WHEN SUM(cs.Conversions)=0 OR SUM(cs.Clicks)=0 THEN 0 ELSE
    (SUM(cs.Conversions)/SUM(cs.Clicks)) END AS cvr,
  
  CASE WHEN SUM(cs.Conversions)=0 OR SUM(cs.Cost)=0 THEN 0 ELSE
    (SUM(cs.Cost)/SUM(cs.Conversions))/1000000 END AS cost_per_conversion

FROM 
  `bold-quanta-######.######_google_ads_dataset.CampaignStats_##########` cs
JOIN
  `bold-quanta-######.queried_permanent_tables.process_campaign_labels` cl
ON
  cs.CampaignId = cl.CampaignId

GROUP BY
  1, 2, 3
```